# zing Charts is making web page slow and laggy

Tags: javascript, html, charts, zingchart

I am currently trying to plot around 200k data (Time and Frequency) on zing Chart. it does load the chart successfully but page gets very heavy and it lags a lot. Here is my code please guide me have I done any Mistake or how can I plot data without page getting laggy.

I am trying to draw 4 charts like this one same webpage different data (which is 200k+ values).

i get data from APi code ...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url:url,
    data: { startTime : '2022-07-25 10-40-12', endTime : '2022-08-22 17-41-14', tableName : tableName },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        drawTimeVSAngleChart(data[0], data[1],data[2]);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

after rec data i just call `drawTimeVSAngleChart` function

```
timeArray , cpuArray, memoryArray these are passed
```

my code

```
function drawTimeVSAngleChart(timeArray , cpuArray, memoryArray){

    $('#lineChart').remove();
    $('#canvas_div').append(
        '<div id="lineChart" style="min-height: 400px; height: 500px; max-height: 500px; max-width: 100%;"></div>'

    );

    var configTimeAndAngle = {
        "type": "line",
        legend: {
            layout: "1x2", //row x column // items means in one two we added two items as in legends
            x: "35%",
            y: "6%",
        },
        "preview":{
            "live":true
        },
        'scale-x': {
            zooming: true,
            labels: timeArray,
            'max-items':8,
            'min-items':7,
            item: {
            'font-size':10
            }
        },
        'scale-y': {
            //zooming: true,
            //values: "50:350:50",
            guide: {
                'line-style': "dotted"
            },
            item: {
            'font-size':10
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            text: 'Time : %kt (X) Freq : %vt (Y).',
            alpha: 0.9,
            backgroundColor: '#F44336',
            borderColor: '#B71C1C',
            borderRadius: 2,
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: '5 10'
        },
        gui: {
            behaviors: [
            {
                id: 'DownloadPDF',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'ViewDataTable',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'ViewSource',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'ZingChart',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'CrosshairHide',
                enabled: 'all'
            }
            ]
        },
        "series": [{
            "values": cpuArray,
            'line-color': "#3366ff",
            'background-color': "#3366ff",
            text: "CPU Array"
            },
            {
            "values": memoryArray,
            'line-color': "#00cc99",
            'background-color': "#00cc99",
            text: "Memory Array"
            }
        ]
    };

    zingchart.render({
        id: 'lineChart',
        data: configTimeAndAngle,
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%"
    });


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this solution is similar to [@lasabahebwa solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74046654/18877734) but its actual solution which I was looking for. I am able to plot 1 million points without any issue. There is a issue from data been plotted. Issue is that when I load chart or apply filter chart takes around 9 seconds to load data. well my solution is
my solution is abit different because I am giving data in different format and time array is used. for details read question.

```
    $('#lineChart_f').remove();
    $('#canvas_div_f').append(
        '<div id="lineChart_f" style="min-height: 400px; height: 550px; max-height: 500px; max-width: 100%;"></div>'
    );


    var configTimeAndAngle = {
        "type": "line",
        noData:{
            text:"No data found",
            backgroundColor: "#20b2db"
        },
        legend: {
            layout: "1x2", //row x column // items means in one two we added two items as in legends
            x: "35%",
            y: "6%",
        },
        "preview":{
            "live":true
        },
        plot: {
            mode: 'fast',
        },
        'scale-x': {
            zooming: true,
            labels: timeArray,
            item: {
            'font-size':10
            }
        },
        'scale-y': {
            'auto-fit': true,
            'min-value':30,
            'max-value':70,
            guide: {
                'line-style': "dotted"
            },
            item: {
            'font-size':10
            }
        },
        'crosshair-x': {
            text: 'Time : %kt (X) Freq : %vt (Y).',
            'line-style': 'dashed',
            'line-width': 2,
            'line-color': '#2196F3',
            marker: {
                type: 'triangle',
                size: 5,
                visible: true
            }
        },
        gui: {
            behaviors: [
            {
                id: 'DownloadPDF',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'ViewDataTable',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'ViewSource',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'ZingChart',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'CrosshairHide',
                enabled: 'all'
            }
            ]
        },
        "series": [{
            "values": frequency_array_ff,
            'line-color': "#3366ff",
            'background-color': "#3366ff",
            text: "Centeral Frequency"
            },
            {
            "values": frequency_array_fh,
            'line-color': "#00cc99",
            'background-color': "#00cc99",
            text: "Frequency Hopping"
            }
        ]
    };

    zingchart.QUOTEDVALUES = true;
    zingchart.render({
        id: "lineChart_f",
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        output: "canvas",
        data: configTimeAndAngle
    });
```

Comment: how do we change the background color of this chart ?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately the current library gets slower as you get into larger datasets (20k+ nodes). How do we combat this? Well, there is no straightforward solution to performance but there are some basic steps you can take to achieve a relative performance gain, such as any combination of the following [methodologies](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/features/performance#solution).

It's also worth noting that ZC3 does 1M data in under 0.1s but unfortunately it's not ready for public.

Comment: I have Loaded around 33k values in Zing Chart and it works perfectly fine and thank you for the methodologies. do you know any other free JavaScript libraries for charts, that can handle large data ?

Comment: this is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74046654/18877734)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any other free JavaScript libraries for charts, that can handle large data.