# zing chart are not being render in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, charts, zingchart

I am trying to plot some heavy data on zing Chart. Zing charts are normally plot inside a div but for my case my page became leggy after loading 200k points inside zing chart div-tag. In the doc it says to load large data in Canvas.
In the performance [documentation](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/features/performance#solution) of zing chart; in the end of document there is **Render type**, it says to load in canvas but its not working. according to doc 
**Render Type**
The render method is where you can define the output, which can either render Canvas or SVG. If you are rendering a large dataset, the performance of Canvas will benefit you because DOM explosion happens when rendering in SVG.

Here is my code any suggestion or help.

```
function chart_timeFreq_ff_fh(timeArray, frequency_array_ff, frequency_array_fh) {
  zingchart.DEV.SORTTOKENS = 0;
  zingchart.DEV.PLOTSTATS = 0;
  zingchart.DEV.RESOURCES = 0;
  zingchart.DEV.KEEPSOURCE = 0;
  zingchart.DEV.COPYDATA = 0;
  zingchart.DEV.MEDIARULES = 0;
  zingchart.SYNTAX = 'dashed';

    $('#lineChart_f').remove();
    $('#canvas_div_f').append(
        '<canvas id="lineChart_f" style="min-height: 400px; height: 550px; max-height: 500px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>'
    );

    let configTimeAndAngle = {
        "type": "line",
        plot: {
        mode: 'fast',
        'hint-ts': true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: "1x2", //row x column // items means in one two we added two items as legends
            x: "35%",
            y: "6%",
        },
        "preview":{
            "live":true
        },
        'scale-x': {
            zooming: true,
            labels: timeArray,
            'max-items':8,
            transform: {
                type: 'date'
            },

            item: {
            'font-size':10
            }
        },
        'scale-y': {
            'auto-fit': true,
            guide: {
                'line-style': "solid"
            },
            item: {
            'font-size':10
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            // text: 'Time : %kt (X) Freq : %%node-value (Y).',
            text: 'Time : %kt (X) Freq : %v (Y).',
            alpha: 0.9,
            backgroundColor: '#F44336',
            borderColor: '#B71C1C',
            borderRadius: 2,
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: '5 10'
        },
        gui: {
            behaviors: [
            {
                id: 'ViewDataTable',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'ViewSource',
                enabled: 'none'
            },
            {
                id: 'CrosshairHide',
                enabled: 'all'
            }
            ]
        },
        "series": [
            {
            "values": frequency_array_ff,
            'line-color': "#3366ff",
            'background-color': "#3366ff",
            text: "Centeral Frequency"
            },
            {
            "values": frequency_array_fh,
            'line-color': "#00cc99",
            'background-color': "#00cc99",
            text: "Frequency Hopping"
            }
        ]
    };



    zingchart.render({
        id: 'lineChart_cob_f',
        data: configTimeAndAngle,
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        output: "canvas"
    });

}
```

**Updated**

I have tried to plot like this but still issue. Above chart is also updated and we i need to change how I pass time ? my time format is like `2022-10-10 23:24:03` an array of time like this so in the         `'scale-x': { labels: timeArray}` i add time like this

```
"series": [
 
            {
                values: [],
                'line-color': "#3366ff",
                'background-color': "#3366ff",
                text: "Centeral Frequency"
            },
            {
                values: [],
                'line-color': "#00cc99",
                'background-color': "#00cc99",
                text: "Frequency Hopping"
            }
        ]
configTimeAndAngle.series[0].values.push([frequency_array_ff]);
configTimeAndAngle.series[1].values.push([frequency_array_fh]);
configTimeAndAngle.series[0]=values.[frequency_array_ff];
configTimeAndAngle.series[1]=values[frequency_array_fh];
configTimeAndAngle.series[0]=frequency_array_ff;
configTimeAndAngle.series[1]=frequency_array_fh];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I also had the same issue all day, then I saw this and I have found the issue on your question. you have use canvas instead use div and while rendering use

```
// this is your code 

$('#canvas_div_f').append(
    '<canvas id="lineChart_f" style="min-height: 400px; height: 550px; max-height: 500px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>'
);
```

instead just use

```
$('#canvas_div_f').append(
    '<div id="lineChart_f" style="min-height: 400px; height: 550px; max-height: 500px; max-width: 100%;"></div>'
);
```

and while render set output to canvas.

```
zingchart.render({
    id: 'lineChart_cob_f',
    data: configTimeAndAngle,
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    output: "canvas"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to create you a [demo](https://app.zingsoft.com/demos/create/34QNKXD7) in a studio application with over 200k nodes, maybe you can use this setup with canvas in the render method for reference and see how it goes. I hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: I have updated the `chart_timeFreq_ff_fh` tried to copy you. it says loading zing chart wait and chart don't appear. second when I pass the values later to the chart it don't work. check below updated above. Also check how i pas time please tell me how to improve my code.

Comment: this is the error comes when I give 3 separate arrays as values. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')`  frequency_array_ff array and frequency_array_fh aray and time array